# TCP Congestion Window in Linux

Tags: linux, tcp, cwd

I'm making some test between two peer (CentOS7) in a 10Gbit network with iperf.

The configuration in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4` and `/proc/sys/net/core` are exactly the same, so every socket buffer default size or tcp logic are identical.

When test run with machine linked directly, without switch or router, everthing works fine in both directions.

When i put a switch in beetween, one direction continue to work very well (about 9,41Gbps), but the other throughput drop to 3-4Gpbs, and the problem reside in the client i suppose.

Here is a log of `ss` command on the socket involved when test goes fine (with swtich but good direction client side)

```
$ ss -t -m -i -e '( dport >= :5201 and dport <= :5300 )'
State       Recv-Q Send-Q                                     Local Address:Port                                                      Peer Address:Port
ESTAB       0      3346328                                      192.168.1.13:targus-getdata3                                           192.168.1.32:targus-getdata3       timer:(on,204ms,0) uid:1000 ino:531203930 sk:ffff9e19879af440 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb369280,t264032,tb4194304,f888440,w3391880,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:204 rtt:3.178/0.136 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:524 ssthresh:223 bytes_acked:5871839852 bytes_received:60 segs_out:4055294 segs_in:849177 send 1910.0Mbps lastrcv:75037 pacing_rate 3819.9Mbps unacked:151 retrans:0/2 reordering:10 rcv_space:43440
ESTAB       0      2410920                                      192.168.1.13:5216                                                      192.168.1.32:5216                  timer:(on,207ms,0) uid:1000 ino:530956112 sk:ffff9e1aac4c5d00 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb369280,t198024,tb3307520,f936904,w2442296,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:207 rtt:6.575/0.321 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:380 ssthresh:285 bytes_acked:3195772228 bytes_received:60 segs_out:2207164 segs_in:584200 send 669.5Mbps lastrcv:75037 pacing_rate 1338.9Mbps unacked:135 retrans:0/2 reordering:9 rcv_space:43440
ESTAB       0      2907584                                      192.168.1.13:5207                                                      192.168.1.32:5207                  timer:(on,204ms,0) uid:1000 ino:531298256 sk:ffff9e1aa64007c0 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb369280,t264032,tb3942912,f1067904,w2946176,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:204 rtt:3.101/0.238 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:453 ssthresh:276 bytes_acked:5872097596 bytes_received:60 segs_out:4055482 segs_in:1087602 send 1692.2Mbps lastrcv:75036 pacing_rate 3384.0Mbps unacked:163 retrans:0/1 reordering:13 rcv_space:43440
ESTAB       0      4105080                                      192.168.1.13:5211                                                      192.168.1.32:5211                  timer:(on,204ms,0) uid:1000 ino:531277263 sk:ffff9e19839e8f80 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb369280,t264032,tb4194304,f109528,w4158504,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:204 rtt:3.204/0.205 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:488 ssthresh:186 bytes_acked:5872007820 bytes_received:60 segs_out:4055438 segs_in:1081061 send 1764.4Mbps lastrcv:75033 pacing_rate 3527.9Mbps unacked:180 retrans:0/2 reordering:9 rcv_space:43440
ESTAB       0      3825616                                      192.168.1.13:targus-getdata1                                           192.168.1.32:targus-getdata1       timer:(on,204ms,0) uid:1000 ino:531339320 sk:ffff9e1c8d622e80 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb369280,t264032,tb4194304,f399120,w3877104,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:204 rtt:3.192/0.274 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:484 ssthresh:184 bytes_acked:5872555164 bytes_received:60 segs_out:4055801 segs_in:1084450 send 1756.5Mbps lastrcv:75036 pacing_rate 3512.0Mbps unacked:167 reordering:9 rcv_space:43440
ESTAB       0      3281944                                      192.168.1.13:5208                                                      192.168.1.32:5208                  timer:(on,204ms,0) uid:1000 ino:531203929 sk:ffff9e198a9dcd80 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb369280,t264032,tb4194304,f948728,w3327496,o0,bl4608,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:204 rtt:3.26/0.175 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:536 ssthresh:243 bytes_acked:5870095012 bytes_received:60 segs_out:4054122 segs_in:854843 send 1904.6Mbps lastrcv:75035 pacing_rate 3808.6Mbps unacked:185 retrans:0/2 reordering:12 rcv_space:43440
ESTAB       0      2814912                                      192.168.1.13:5215                                                      192.168.1.32:5215                  timer:(on,204ms,0) uid:1000 ino:531336741 sk:ffff9e1ab786c5c0 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb369280,t264032,tb4194304,f1434832,w2853680,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:204 rtt:3.159/0.152 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:592 ssthresh:274 bytes_acked:5871974516 bytes_received:60 segs_out:4055425 segs_in:857804 send 2170.9Mbps lastrcv:75037 pacing_rate 4340.5Mbps unacked:189 retrans:0/3 reordering:33 rcv_space:43440
ESTAB       0      3793760                                      192.168.1.13:nomad                                                     192.168.1.32:nomad                 timer:(on,204ms,0) uid:1000 ino:531279592 sk:ffff9e1ad35d9740 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb369280,t264032,tb4194304,f443264,w3845248,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:204 rtt:3.226/0.141 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:579 ssthresh:115 bytes_acked:5870063156 bytes_received:60 segs_out:4054104 segs_in:828650 send 2079.1Mbps lastrcv:75034 pacing_rate 4157.4Mbps unacked:190 retrans:0/1 reordering:8 rcv_space:43440
ESTAB       0      3053832                                      192.168.1.13:5206                                                      192.168.1.32:5206                  timer:(on,204ms,0) uid:1000 ino:531341868 sk:ffff9e1ad888d540 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb369280,t264032,tb4194304,f1189272,w3095144,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:204 rtt:3.204/0.247 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:572 ssthresh:266 bytes_acked:5872523308 bytes_received:60 segs_out:4055788 segs_in:1088650 send 2068.1Mbps lastrcv:75039 pacing_rate 4135.1Mbps unacked:174 retrans:0/1 reordering:10 rcv_space:43440
ESTAB       0      0                                          10.180.244.35:47750                                                  185.142.153.241:5207                  timer:(keepalive,44min,0) uid:986 ino:942443 sk:ffff9e1ab700f440 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb367360,t0,tb46080,f0,w0,o0,bl0,d31) ts sack cubic wscale:8,7 rto:419 rtt:218.784/0.245 ato:55 mss:1368 rcvmss:740 advmss:1448 cwnd:3 ssthresh:2 bytes_acked:834310 bytes_received:2580548 segs_out:22886 segs_in:45440 send 150.1Kbps lastsnd:10219 lastrcv:10219 lastack:10000 pacing_rate 300.1Kbps retrans:0/8 rcv_rtt:16328 rcv_space:29200
ESTAB       0      3379632                                      192.168.1.13:targus-getdata2                                           192.168.1.32:targus-getdata2       timer:(on,204ms,0) uid:1000 ino:531317093 sk:ffff9e198bfde4c0 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb369280,t264032,tb4194304,f842848,w3425184,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:204 rtt:3.267/0.242 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:520 ssthresh:240 bytes_acked:5871207076 bytes_received:60 segs_out:4054879 segs_in:867131 send 1843.8Mbps lastrcv:75039 pacing_rate 3687.4Mbps unacked:174 retrans:0/2 reordering:10 rcv_space:43440
ESTAB       0      2772920                                      192.168.1.13:5214                                                      192.168.1.32:5214                  timer:(on,206ms,0) uid:1000 ino:531325347 sk:ffff9e1aac4c1740 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb369280,t198024,tb3176960,f429096,w2810840,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:207 rtt:6.258/0.642 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:365 ssthresh:177 bytes_acked:2676851020 bytes_received:60 segs_out:1848773 segs_in:489790 send 675.6Mbps lastsnd:4 lastrcv:75037 lastack:1 pacing_rate 1351.2Mbps unacked:115 retrans:0/2 reordering:8 rcv_space:43440
ESTAB       0      3858920                                      192.168.1.13:5210                                                      192.168.1.32:5210                  timer:(on,204ms,0) uid:1000 ino:531323601 sk:ffff9e19a6dea6c0 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb369280,t264032,tb4194304,f369064,w3911256,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:204 rtt:3.161/0.186 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:502 ssthresh:271 bytes_acked:5871582108 bytes_received:60 segs_out:4055110 segs_in:1087690 send 1839.7Mbps lastsnd:1 lastrcv:75037 pacing_rate 3679.0Mbps unacked:145 retrans:0/3 reordering:13 rcv_space:43440
ESTAB       0      3974760                                      192.168.1.13:5213                                                      192.168.1.32:5213                  timer:(on,203ms,0) uid:1000 ino:530956111 sk:ffff9e1a0fbf07c0 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb369280,t264032,tb4194304,f251272,w4029048,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:204 rtt:3.245/0.221 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:522 ssthresh:17 bytes_acked:5869792380 bytes_received:60 segs_out:4053913 segs_in:1091433 send 1863.4Mbps lastsnd:1 lastrcv:75033 lastack:1 pacing_rate 3726.7Mbps unacked:180 retrans:0/7 sacked:2 reordering:8 rcv_space:43440
ESTAB       0      2869936                                      192.168.1.13:5205                                                      192.168.1.32:5205                  timer:(on,204ms,0) uid:1000 ino:531298257 sk:ffff9e1c373fbe00 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb369280,t264032,tb4194304,f1362576,w2909552,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:204 rtt:3.152/0.231 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:561 ssthresh:348 bytes_acked:5871411244 bytes_received:60 segs_out:4055029 segs_in:850916 send 2061.7Mbps lastsnd:1 lastrcv:75040 pacing_rate 4122.7Mbps unacked:182 retrans:0/3 reordering:20 rcv_space:43440
ESTAB       0      2974192                                      192.168.1.13:5204                                                      192.168.1.32:5204                  timer:(on,203ms,0) uid:1000 ino:530585403 sk:ffff9e19829e0f80 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb369280,t264032,tb4194304,f1265664,w3014656,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:204 rtt:3.189/0.265 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:662 ssthresh:196 bytes_acked:5872327828 bytes_received:60 segs_out:4055645 segs_in:837871 send 2404.7Mbps lastsnd:1 lastrcv:75039 lastack:1 pacing_rate 4809.2Mbps unacked:164 retrans:0/3 reordering:11 rcv_space:43440
ESTAB       0      3383976                                      192.168.1.13:5212                                                      192.168.1.32:5212                  timer:(on,204ms,0) uid:1000 ino:531325348 sk:ffff9e1aacee1f00 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb369280,t264032,tb4194304,f854888,w3429528,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:204 rtt:3.154/0.197 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:504 ssthresh:177 bytes_acked:5871947004 bytes_received:60 segs_out:4055394 segs_in:1092830 send 1851.1Mbps lastsnd:1 lastrcv:75033 pacing_rate 3701.7Mbps unacked:177 retrans:0/3 reordering:8 rcv_space:43440
```

and this one int he bad direction

```
State       Recv-Q Send-Q                                     Local Address:Port                                                      Peer Address:Port
ESTAB       0      230232                                      192.168.1.32:55347                                                     192.168.1.13:targus-getdata1       timer:(on,087ms,0) uid:1000 ino:3314212 sk:ffff9f2dc90445c0 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb367360,t0,tb287232,f92600,w239176,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:201 rtt:0.141/0.024 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:3 ssthresh:2 bytes_acked:1152848429 bytes_received:28 segs_out:818686 segs_in:316443 send 246.5Mbps lastsnd:114 lastrcv:86272 lastack:114 pacing_rate 491.6Mbps unacked:4 retrans:0/22512 sacked:1 rcv_space:42340
ESTAB       0      476392                                      192.168.1.32:47801                                                     192.168.1.13:5212                  timer:(on,112ms,0) uid:1000 ino:3314214 sk:ffff9f2dc90426c0 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb367360,t0,tb435200,f32744,w487448,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:201 rtt:0.174/0.142 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:2 ssthresh:2 bytes_acked:1229032053 bytes_received:28 segs_out:872417 segs_in:348168 send 133.1Mbps lastsnd:89 lastrcv:86272 lastack:89 pacing_rate 398.3Mbps unacked:3 retrans:0/23631 sacked:1 rcv_space:42340
ESTAB       0      516936                                      192.168.1.32:32797                                                     192.168.1.13:5216                  timer:(on,010ms,0) uid:1000 ino:3314223 sk:ffff9f2dc9041740 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb367360,t8184,tb513536,f20872,w527992,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:201 rtt:0.113/0.008 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:3 ssthresh:2 bytes_acked:751517725 bytes_received:28 segs_out:533526 segs_in:199119 send 307.5Mbps lastrcv:86268 pacing_rate 611.7Mbps unacked:3 retrans:0/14511 rcv_space:42340
ESTAB       0      104256                                      192.168.1.32:33146                                                     192.168.1.13:5204                  timer:(on,010ms,0) uid:1000 ino:3312994 sk:ffff9f2db3d7a6c0 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb367360,t8184,tb165376,f119152,w110224,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:201 rtt:0.139/0.021 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:3 ssthresh:2 bytes_acked:1270737965 bytes_received:28 segs_out:902063 segs_in:366789 send 250.0Mbps lastrcv:86273 pacing_rate 500.0Mbps unacked:3 retrans:0/24474 rcv_space:42340
ESTAB       0      417024                                      192.168.1.32:56956                                                     192.168.1.13:5210                  timer:(on,201ms,0) uid:1000 ino:3312999 sk:ffff9f2db3d79740 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb367360,t9632,tb435200,f67104,w428512,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:201 rtt:0.13/0.011 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:4 ssthresh:4 bytes_acked:1156831877 bytes_received:28 segs_out:821362 segs_in:316618 send 356.4Mbps lastrcv:86272 pacing_rate 1960.4Mbps unacked:12 retrans:1/22428 lost:1 sacked:8 rcv_space:42340
ESTAB       0      444536                                      192.168.1.32:56215                                                     192.168.1.13:5213                  timer:(on,010ms,0) uid:1000 ino:3313000 sk:ffff9f2db3d7b640 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb367360,t8184,tb435200,f65448,w454744,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:201 rtt:0.128/0.006 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:3 ssthresh:2 bytes_acked:1458483581 bytes_received:28 segs_out:1035626 segs_in:402065 send 271.5Mbps lastrcv:86272 pacing_rate 541.4Mbps unacked:3 retrans:0/28378 rcv_space:42340
ESTAB       0      212856                                      192.168.1.32:41928                                                     192.168.1.13:5214                  timer:(on,010ms,0) uid:1000 ino:3313001 sk:ffff9f2db3d787c0 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb367360,t8184,tb304640,f123544,w220520,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:201 rtt:0.126/0.009 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:3 ssthresh:2 bytes_acked:1256332645 bytes_received:28 segs_out:891525 segs_in:344577 send 275.8Mbps lastrcv:86268 pacing_rate 549.4Mbps unacked:3 retrans:0/23885 rcv_space:42340
ESTAB       0      143352                                      192.168.1.32:58690                                                     192.168.1.13:5205                  timer:(on,141ms,0) uid:1000 ino:3312996 sk:ffff9f2db3d7ec80 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb367360,t0,tb174080,f120168,w150168,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:201 rtt:0.127/0.003 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:2 ssthresh:2 bytes_acked:1426351013 bytes_received:28 segs_out:1012369 segs_in:396073 send 182.4Mbps lastsnd:60 lastrcv:86272 lastack:60 pacing_rate 726.1Mbps unacked:5 retrans:1/27311 lost:1 sacked:3 rcv_space:42340
ESTAB       0      134664                                      192.168.1.32:45540                                                     192.168.1.13:5211                  timer:(on,010ms,0) uid:1000 ino:3314216 sk:ffff9f2dc90464c0 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb367360,t8184,tb174080,f113752,w140200,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:201 rtt:0.148/0.042 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:3 ssthresh:2 bytes_acked:1139529725 bytes_received:28 segs_out:808670 segs_in:326992 send 234.8Mbps lastrcv:86272 pacing_rate 466.9Mbps unacked:3 retrans:0/21695 rcv_space:42340
ESTAB       0      127424                                      192.168.1.32:34184                                                     192.168.1.13:targus-getdata2       timer:(on,010ms,0) uid:1000 ino:3312995 sk:ffff9f2db3d78f80 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb367360,t8184,tb174080,f108272,w133392,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:201 rtt:0.128/0.006 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:3 ssthresh:2 bytes_acked:1527909389 bytes_received:28 segs_out:1084467 segs_in:427388 send 271.5Mbps lastrcv:86272 pacing_rate 541.9Mbps unacked:3 retrans:0/29274 rcv_space:42340
ESTAB       0      130320                                      192.168.1.32:42723                                                     192.168.1.13:nomad                 timer:(on,010ms,0) uid:1000 ino:3312997 sk:ffff9f2db3d7c5c0 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb367360,t7752,tb182784,f114000,w135856,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:201 rtt:0.152/0.045 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:3 ssthresh:2 bytes_acked:1288660693 bytes_received:28 segs_out:914064 segs_in:373200 send 228.6Mbps lastrcv:86269 pacing_rate 456.9Mbps unacked:3 retrans:0/24098 rcv_space:42340
ESTAB       0      110048                                      192.168.1.32:34972                                                     192.168.1.13:targus-getdata3       timer:(on,076ms,0) uid:1000 ino:3314211 sk:ffff9f2dc9045540 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb367360,t0,tb165376,f121552,w116016,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:201 rtt:0.108/0.015 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:2 ssthresh:2 bytes_acked:1500525077 bytes_received:28 segs_out:1064664 segs_in:415032 send 214.5Mbps lastsnd:125 lastrcv:86272 lastack:125 pacing_rate 642.8Mbps unacked:4 retrans:1/28381 lost:1 sacked:2 rcv_space:42340
ESTAB       0      325800                                      192.168.1.32:43465                                                     192.168.1.13:5208                  timer:(on,096ms,0) uid:1000 ino:3312998 sk:ffff9f2db3d7d540 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb367360,t0,tb304640,f10184,w333880,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:201 rtt:0.207/0.161 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:2 ssthresh:2 bytes_acked:1195816381 bytes_received:28 segs_out:848449 segs_in:331177 send 111.9Mbps lastsnd:105 lastrcv:86272 lastack:105 pacing_rate 557.9Mbps unacked:5 retrans:1/22600 lost:1 sacked:3 rcv_space:42340
ESTAB       0      225888                                      192.168.1.32:49260                                                     192.168.1.13:5215                  timer:(on,010ms,0) uid:1000 ino:3313010 sk:ffff9f2db3d78000 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb367360,t8184,tb330752,f122800,w233552,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:201 rtt:0.126/0.01 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:3 ssthresh:2 bytes_acked:1268630509 bytes_received:28 segs_out:900567 segs_in:353282 send 275.8Mbps lastrcv:86268 pacing_rate 550.0Mbps unacked:3 retrans:0/24434 rcv_space:42340
ESTAB       0      296840                                      192.168.1.32:36581                                                     192.168.1.13:5206                  timer:(on,010ms,0) uid:1000 ino:3314213 sk:ffff9f2dc9043640 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb367360,t0,tb435200,f190264,w305352,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:201 rtt:0.128/0.005 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:3 ssthresh:2 bytes_acked:1142285269 bytes_received:28 segs_out:810910 segs_in:324374 send 271.5Mbps lastrcv:86272 pacing_rate 540.4Mbps unacked:3 retrans:0/22031 rcv_space:42340
ESTAB       0      131768                                      192.168.1.32:55639                                                     192.168.1.13:5207                  timer:(on,010ms,0) uid:1000 ino:3314215 sk:ffff9f2dc9040f80 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb367360,t7752,tb182784,f112552,w137304,o0,bl0,d0) ts sack cubic wscale:11,11 rto:201 rtt:0.126/0.012 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:536 advmss:1448 cwnd:3 ssthresh:2 bytes_acked:971172213 bytes_received:28 segs_out:690051 segs_in:276486 send 275.8Mbps lastrcv:86272 pacing_rate 549.4Mbps unacked:3 retrans:0/19345 rcv_space:42340
```

I noticed the `cwnd` and `ssthresh` are very different and i can't figure out why. I've also took down a tcpdump and in the bad direction i've got `TCP Retrasmission` `TCP DUP Ack` or `TCP out-of-order` in a significant percentage.

Maybe the switch privileges some port for some reason? Where i can investigate? There's some i can do to prevente retrasmission for latency?

I've tried to edit the ip route adding `initcwnd 200` or `ssthresh 200` or `rto_min 50ms` but nothing happen

Comment: If it's related to the switch, did you try changing switch ports, or cables or... Eg: unplug the peer1's cable from its switch port, unplug peer2's cable from its switch port, replug the peer2's cable to the previous peer1's port, and replug peer1 to the previous peer2's port: do the perf tests change? Else, instead of swapping ports, swap cables. Etc.